# Using nested generics in Map inside a templated Class

Tags: java, templates, dictionary, generics

I've been struggling with nested generics for a while now. This is what I've been able to do for now:
Basically I have some types of CSV's and a concrete class that manages these types and does operations like mapping a certain complicated type to a CSV Type. And every CSV Type extends 2 interfaces `Cleanable` and `Modifiable`. 
I have a templated class like this:

```
class CSVManager<CSVType extends Cleanable & Modifiable> {
    private Class templateType;
    public CSVManager() {
        templateType = ReflectionUtils.getTemplatedParameterClass(this.getClass());
    }
    public CSVType mapToCSVType(ComplexType data) {

    }
}
```

I have a `Mapper` Interface that my mappers implement

```
interface Mapper<Source, Destination> {
    Destination map(Source source);
}
```

And CSV Types are like

```
class Type1 implements Cleanable, Modifiable {
    // Fields here
}
```

Okay so I have defined Mappers as

```
class ComplexTypeToType1Mapper implements Mapper<ComplexType, Type1> {
    @Override
    Type1 map(ComplexType complexType) {
        // Map fields to type and return
        return new Type1();
    }
}
```

Now basically what I wanted to do was to get a Mapper based on the type of Manager that's been created. So I created a static HashMap inside CSVManager class like this

```
private static Map<Class, Mapper<ComplexType, ?> mapperMap = createMappersMap();
private static Map<Class, Mapper<ComplexType, ?> createMappersMap() {
    Map<Class, Mapper<ComplexType, ?> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put(Type1.class, new ComplexTypeToType1Mapper());
    // other mappers
    return hashMap;
}
```

The first error I get is here. I can't put a concrete type of Mapper in the map.

The reason I'm trying to add this here is because I want my `mapToCSVType` function to just get the mapper and execute map and return the concretely typed instance of the CSV Type. This is what I did in that function

```
public CSVType mapToCSVType(ComplexType data) {
    return (CSVType)mapperMap.get(templateType).map(data); // This should return concrete type like Type1 etc, not the interface
}
```

But this doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here? I am trying to avoid if conditions for each type thats why I'm using a Map to get me the exact mapper. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with, it does not work? It does not compile, it does not work at run time? what exception is it throwing?

Comment: Also where is the key  ```templateType``` you are using coming from?

Comment: I get a compileTime error. I'm getting `templateType` from the current class's template that is being passed in.
Update: That didn't work so i'm explicitly requesting the type while instantiating the Manager's object.

Comment: Could you name the library (and version) containing the `ReflectionUtils` class you use?